# Executing a method from another class in Java... and more

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a method that returns a list of items called findItemByPIdEndDate() and its found inside MngtImpl.java class. Now I'd like to execute this method every once in a while, hourly lets say so here is what I did so far :

This is CronSchedule.java

```
import org.quartz.CronTrigger;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;

public class CronSchedule {
  public CronSchedule ()throws Exception {
    SchedulerFactory sf=new StdSchedulerFactory();
    Scheduler sched=sf.getScheduler();
    JobDetail jd=new JobDetail("job1","group1",CronJob.class);
    CronTrigger ct=new CronTrigger("cronTrigger","group2","0 * * * * ?");
    sched.scheduleJob(jd,ct);
    sched.start();
  }
  public static void main(String args[]){
    try{    
        new CronSchedule();          //Class where cron is created
    }catch(Exception e){}
  }                                 
}
```

Now with this one I have problems. This class is called from the class above based on time constraints (* in parenthesis) and it executes method of MngtImpl class.

```
import org.quartz.Job;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionContext;
import org.quartz.JobExecutionException;

import com.rosa.MngtImpl;

public class CronJob implements Job  {
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
          try {
                  MngtImpl pers = new MngtImpl();
                  pers.findItemByPIdEndDate();
        } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
        }
  }
}
```

Here is the method I try to invoke from the above class. This method is found inside class named MngtImpl.java

```
 public List<Long> findItemByPIdEndDate() throws Exception {

                List<Long> list = null;

                try{
                        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();   
                        Query query = session.getNamedQuery("endDateChecker");
                        list = query.list();

                }catch (HibernateException e){
                        throw new DataAccessException(e.getMessage());
                }

                return list;
        }
```

Now here is what I'd like to do. I need to run this this above method based on some amount of time(which I could specify anytime). I need to make a bean inside bean factory xml file that actually instances this scheduler and calls this method, and I tried this by calling CronJob.java from CronScheldule.java which calls method from another class and I made a bean which maybe working or not

```
<bean id="cronSchedule" class="com.mypackage.CronSchedule">
        </bean>
```

But its not working as I expected and its pretty complicated, may I get some help with code please? Thank you

I encounter the following exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException 11:10:46,410 ERROR [STDERR]
   at com.packftc.RulesManager.exception(RulesManager.java:25) 11:10:46,410 ERROR [STDERR]
   at org.drools.agent.RuleAgent$2.run(RuleAgent.java:442) 11:10:46,410 ERROR [STDERR]
   at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source) 11:10:46,410 ERROR [STDERR]
   at java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This is obviously wrong way of doing this I've tried like zilion things so far : Here is what I'm trying to do in simple words, I want to execute findItemByPIdEndDate() method from MngtImpl class every lets say minute. Method is functioning properly I wrote a test and it passes it. So what do I do now ? Thank you

Comment: The phrasing of your question is a bit complicated to understand :-( You seem to have the basic idea. I suggest you ask a more precise question on what exactly is not working.

Comment: `But its not working as I expected` 
Sorry but this does not help. What is it doing? 
Also if you are using Spring - I thought it has some nice wrappers for Quartz, have you tried them?

Comment: I thought it has some nice wrappers for Quartz, have you tried them? Which ones, I didn't know .. "But its not working as I expected" I should get a list .. but instead I'm getting an exception ,Null Pointer

Comment: If you're getting an exception then for goddness' sake, **post the stack trace** - this will show exactly where your problem is and also probably what is null.  Without this information it will be orders of magnitude harder to help you.

Comment: Next question - what's happening in com.packftc.RulesManager?  Is this your code or library code?  In any case it seems like you have a problem with your rule base - the RuleAgent task is handing this exception over to your listener, which is failing to do anything with it due to the NPE.  Are you logging what this actual exception was anywhere, as this is the root cause?

Comment: Can you please elaborate ur question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a pointer since I could not make much by the stack trace, but it appears the problem is in `pers.findItemByPIdEndDate();` since the code works fine when I replace the Hibernate stuff with a plain java class.

Also I supplied the CronTrigger pattern as `0/5 * * * * ?` so to run it per 5 second. Your current pattern does not fire the job at all.

See if this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

If executing a task periodically is the problem here (I'm not quite sure) I suggest using ScheduledExecutorService, which is part of JDK 1.5 and later:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class SchedulerExample {

private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
       Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);

public void activateHourlyDataRetrieval() {

        Runnable dataRetriever = new Runnable() {

           MngtImpl pers = new MngtImpl();

           public void run() {

               pers.findItemByPIdEndDate();

            }
         };

        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(dataRetriever, 0, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
}
}
```

Comment: I'm getting a compile error "TimeUnit.HOURS cannot be resolved " Do I need to create any beans inside appcontext ?

Comment: Did you remember to import <code>java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit</code>? Are you using JDK 1.5 or later?

Comment: I changed the time to seconds.. still nothing

Comment: Marco - the problem is an NPE, as the OP alluded to in comments to his question, but still has not shown the stacktrace of (hint, hint).